# I want to display event dynamically in fullcalendar 3.0.1

Tags: javascript, events, fullcalendar

below is  my code. i don't know why the calendar are working but no event displayed. I very appreciate your help.

```
var eventSTR = [{start: '2016-11-21',end: '2016-11-23',overlap: false,rendering : 'background', color: '#ff9f89'},];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month',
            },
            defaultDate: today,
            navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            businessHours: true, // display business hours
            editable: false,
            event : eventSTR
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're 99% there, just missing 2 things

1) you need to set the today variable before you set the document ready function:

```
var today = new Date();
```

2) you've misspelled the events property. You have:

```
event : eventSTR
```

it should read:

```
events : eventSTR
```